# dimensionality reduction for specific character data (not a text)

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am not an expert in this field, so my question may be stupid, so I apologize in advance.

I'm looking for a way to reduce the dimension for my data, it can be PCA or something else, the main thing is that it works, and it is important that it be possible to predict new data

here is the code to generate data similar to mine

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(ncol = 3,nrow = 100)
make.rnd.rule <- function(){
rule <- c()
for(i in 1:sample(3,1)){
le <- sample(LETTERS,1)
id <- sample(20,1)
rl <- sample(c(">","<","=="),1)
vl <- sample(200,1)
res <- paste0(le,"[",id,"]",rl,vl)
rule <- c(rule,res)}
return(paste(rule,collapse = " & "))}
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(m))  m[i,j] <- make.rnd.rule()
}
```

This is how my data looks like

```
head(m)
     [,1]                               [,2]                               
[1,] "O[19]<195 & J[18]<43 & E[20]<118" "Z[5]==91"                         
[2,] "Y[9]>99"                          "G[10]>164 & N[17]==103"           
[3,] "L[15]<109"                        "I[9]<23 & U[7]>155 & F[2]>69"     
[4,] "M[18]>91 & Y[6]>41 & O[16]<6"     "H[7]==118 & R[17]<4 & M[5]<127"   
[5,] "Y[20]<89 & N[3]<140 & Y[14]<64"   "N[7]==151 & V[15]>165 & H[19]<178"
[6,] "L[2]<127 & L[20]<17"              "N[3]<94 & O[17]==107"
```

I will be glad for any help

Comment: What does it mean to reduce the dimension of a string of text? Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve and how "dimension reduction" of the text relates to solving it?

Comment: Hi  Sycorax!     I would like to convert my data into the form of several vectors, I need this in order to analyze how "these vectors" have changed over time, as well as to predict new data ...

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about [tag:embeddings].